# numpy Polynomial.fit returns unrealistic values

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I would like to fit a polynomial to a series of x/y-datapoints and evaluate it at arbitrary x-values. I am using [the new `numpy` polynomial API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [50.0, 150.0, 250.0, 400.0, 600.0, 850.0, 1000.0]
y = [3.2, 10.1, 16.3, 43.7, 69.1, 45.2, 10.8]

mypol = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    deg = 3,
)
np.polyval(mypol.coef, x)
```

Unfortunately, this returns values which are far greater than the original y-values:

```
array([7.34024294e+06, 1.96122504e+08, 9.06027339e+08, 3.70658027e+09,
       1.25012342e+10, 3.55289563e+10, 5.78446450e+10])
```

I played around with the order of the polynomial, but wasn't able to get anything useful from the function. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's `polyval` should be evaluated at the x-points, not the y-points. On top of that, the coefficients should be given in order of highest to lowest degree. That said, `mypol.coef` does not necessarily return the expanded polynomial coefficients, so `mypol.coef` may be useless for `np.polyval`.

Instead, the `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial` object returned by `numpy.polynomial.Polynomial.fit` can be evaluated at the x-points of interest, i.e. you can do `mypol(x)`. Just note that `x` here should be a numpy array. Also note that the fit polynomial is a least-squares fit, meaning it is not an exact interpolation.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

x = np.array([50.0, 150.0, 250.0, 400.0, 600.0, 850.0, 1000.0])
y = np.array([3.2, 10.1, 16.3, 43.7, 69.1, 45.2, 10.8])

mypol = Polynomial.fit(x, y, 3)

x_fine = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
y_fine = mypol(x_fine)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, label="data")
ax.plot(x_fine, y_fine, "tab:orange", label="fit")
ax.set(xlabel="x", ylabel="y", title="NumPy Polynomial Fit")
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Polynomial degrees are in ascending order. polyval in descending
2. Polynomial use a domain. Your domain is (50, 1000), that are mapped to (-1, 1).

Proof

```py
xx=-1; sum(mypol.coef[i]*xx**i for i in range(4))
mypol(50)
```

Likewise

```py
xx=1; sum(mypol.coef[i]*xx**i for i in range(4))
mypol(1000)
return the same thing
```

Said otherwise, the coefficient of `mypol.coef` are the coefficient, in ascending order, of a polynomial to be applied to mapping of xx from `x.min()` to `x.max()` onto (-1,1).

So

```py
mypol.coef[0] + mypol.coef[1]*(x/475-525/475) + mypol.coef[2]*(x/475-525/475)**2 + mypol.coef[3]*(x/475-525/475)**3
# array([ 1.95553575,  9.3341046 , 21.31483053, 42.50405079, 63.77733143, 51.3251079 ,  8.189039  ])
# is same as
mypol(x)
# array([ 1.95553575,  9.3341046 , 21.31483053, 42.50405079, 63.77733143, 51.3251079 ,  8.189039  ])
```

If you want to convert your `mypol.coef` into a plain coefficients, you can develop that expression

```
import sympy
x=sympy.symbols("x")
sympy.simplify(mypol.coef[0] + mypol.coef[1]*(x/475-525/475) + mypol.coef[2]*(x/475-525/475)**2 + mypol.coef[3]*(x/475-525/475)**3)
# -4.12260050136194e-7*x**3 + 0.000415624876439054*x**2 + 0.00405916487759128*x + 0.765047817718013
```